# Sort of regmon/procmon for wine

Tags: wine

Is there some registry tracking software for wine? There is a Sysinternals app [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (descendant of [RegMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx)) that doesn't start under wine. So, I'd like to find some alternative of this application to work under wine. Do you know any?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried 'wine regedit'? This will run the wine GUI regedit ...

Comment: Thank you. However, regedit doesn't alike to Procmon. Have a look at the example of ProcMon using http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SH_JqB_XwWg